# How do I get Gmail to recognize times & dates for Google Calendar creation?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

For some reason Gmail does not recognize times or dates in order to create Calendar events. I'm using Chrome in Windows 7 and logged into both accounts.

I think it stopped working around 3 or 4 months ago.

I've tried uninstalling all extensions, clearing history and cookies.

Comment: Calendar Settings > General > "Events from Gmail:" ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No dice on changing the settings :(

Comment: Perhaps the google lab "Google Calendar gadget" would help.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Gave that a shot, no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do one of these maybe explain your issue?

[Why events may not show up in Calendar](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084018?st-idx=10,11#missing_events)

> There are a few reasons why an event from Gmail may not show up in Calendar:
>
> - Events from Gmail aren't available for Government accounts, or Google Accounts that don't have Gmail.
> - Not all languages are supported yet. We're working to add support for more languages.
> - Events won't show up if the email was forwarded to you or sent to a mailing list. The email has to be sent directly to you.
> - Events are only added if they are from confirmation emails about flights, hotels, restaurants, and ticketed events like movies and concerts. These emails are generally sent by businesses.  Events in personal emails are not added to Calendar, like a conversation about plans to see a movie with friends.
> - If you had turned this feature off and then back on, only events in the future will be added, not past events.
>
> If you received a confirmation email in Gmail about an event, but it hasn't been added to your calendar automatically, report the issue by sending us feedback. In your feedback report, it would be helpful if you include the sender email address. Learn how to [send feedback](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6110973).

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly- your Gmail does not recognize date and time details on emails.

From what I've observed: Gmail usually recognizes time and date on emails from Other accounts. It does not recognize them on emails sent from the user's account itself .

All recipients (except the sender) will be able to create Calendar events from the date and time in the email.